# Gradle - "override" behaviour/properties from build.gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I'm not a Gradle expert by any means so please be gentle...

I have a Gradle build which I'm trying to run on Jenkins. The build.gradle contains the following:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://some_internal_corporate_repo"
    }
}
```

The Jenkins server that I am running the job on cannot access "some_internal_corporate_repo".

As **I can't modify** the build.gradle I would like to know if there's a way I can somehow extend or override the build.gradle, on the Jenkins server, to point to mavenCentral (or similar), maybe via an init file or setting a property etc?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: in the end, because I was using Jenkins, I used it's Groovy support (execute Groovy build step) to address my issue:

```
def file = new File('build.gradle')
def newConfig = file.text.replace('url "http://some_internal_corporate_repo"', 'url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/"')
file.text = newConfig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can define** [multiple repositories](http://The%20order%20of%20declaration%20determines%20how%20Gradle%20will%20check%20for%20dependencies%20at%20runtime).

> The order of declaration determines how Gradle will check for dependencies at runtime

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://some_internal_corporate_repo"
    }
    mavenCentral() 
}
```

**You can use a properties** to define the maven repo url:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "${repositories_maven_url}"
    }
}
```

In the `gradle.properties` file

```
repositories_maven_url=maven_url
```

According to the [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties), `gradle.properties` files are applied in the following order:

- `gradle.properties` in project root directory.
- `gradle.properties` in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory.
- system properties, e.g. when `-Dgradle.user.home` is set on the command line.

Or **you can use something like this**:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url getMavenUrl()
        }
}

/**
 * Returns the url of the maven repo.
 * Set this value in your ~/.gradle/gradle.properties with repositories_maven_url key
 * If the property is not defined returns a default value
 * @return
 */
def getMavenUrl() {
    return hasProperty('repositories_maven_url') ? repositories_maven_url : "YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll get some time to look at this later (and then hopefully accept)

Comment: It looks like all of the above require changing, to some extent, build.gradle, is this correct? Is there any solution where changing the original build.gradle is not required?

Comment: @LawrenceTierney obviously at least one change is required. The only alternative is to check why the Jenkins machine is unable to reach the maven repo.